# How to get difference between N dates in moment js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

I have a scenario in which i have to subtract 3 dates and the result should be on the basis of minutes.

I've tried taking the epoch time of these three dates and subtract it with each other. But it will give me date.

```js
let a = moment('2020-04-20 15:48:00', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").valueOf();
let b = moment('2020-04-20 15:53:00', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").valueOf();
let c = moment('2020-04-20 16:05:00', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").valueOf();

let result = Math.abs(a - b - c);

console.log(new Date(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Kindly help me in finding the difference in minutes.

Comment: *result* will be in milliseconds, so just divide by 6e4 (milliseconds in 1 minute). What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: actually the difference i got is -1587379200000 -> i guess it can't be converted to minutes. For difference between two it is working fine though @RobG

Comment: What is the difference between three values? A difference can only exist between two values.

Comment: @wederer Yes that is an issue.Unfortunately It's comes under requirements.

Comment: Then the requirements are not specified correctly. Ask for examples or a definition.

Answer (score 0):

Part of what makes momentjs such a great package is that it provides some nice functions to do date math with. Have a look at the docs on the `diff` method here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

you can do `((a - b) - c)` as

```
const minsBetweenAAndB = a.diff(b, 'minutes');
const result = c.subtract(minsBetweenAAndB, 'minutes')
```